# Alamofire v4 use of undeclared type response

Tags: swift, xcode, alamofire

When I updated to Alamofire v4 I got two errors.

The first one is **use of undeclared type response** which I get from this line:

```
func responseSavedAdsArray(_ completionHandler: (Response<SavedAdsWrapper, NSError>) ->
```

The second error is **use of unresolved identifier ResponseSerializer** which I get from this line:

```
let responseSerializer = ResponseSerializer<SavedAdsWrapper, NSError> { request, response, data, error in
```

Here is all my code:

```
extension Alamofire.Request {
    func responseSavedArray(_ completionHandler: (Response<SavedWrapper, NSError>) -> Void) -> Self {
        let responseSerializer = ResponseSerializer<SavedWrapper, NSError> { request, response, data, error in
            guard error == nil else {
                return .Failure(error!)
            }
            guard let responseData = data else {
                let failureReason = "Array could not be serialized because input data was nil."
                let userInfo: Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject> = [NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey: failureReason, Error.UserInfoKeys.StatusCode: response!.statusCode]
                let error = NSError(domain: Error.Domain, code: Error.Code.StatusCodeValidationFailed.rawValue, userInfo: userInfo)
                return .Failure(error)
            }

            let JSONResponseSerializer = Request.JSONResponseSerializer(options: .AllowFragments)
            let result = JSONResponseSerializer.serializeResponse(request, response, responseData, error)

            switch result {
            case .Success(let value):
                let json = JSON(value)
                let wrapper = SavedWrapper()

                wrapper.next = json["saveditems"]["next_page_url"].stringValue
                wrapper.previous = json["saveditems"]["prev_page_url"].stringValue
                wrapper.count = json["saveditems"]["total"].intValue

                var allSaved:Array = Array<Saved>()
                print(json)
                let results = json["saveditems"]["data"]
                print(results)
                for jsonAdata in results
                {

                    let adsJData = SavedAds(json: jsonAdata.1, id: Int(jsonAdata.0))
                    allSaved.append(adsJData)
                }
                wrapper.saveditems = allSaved
                return .Success(wrapper)
            case .Failure(let error):
                return .Failure(error)
            }
        }

        return response(responseSerializer: responseSerializer,
                        completionHandler: completionHandler)
    }
}
```

So what is causing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change first

```
func responseSavedAdsArray(_ completionHandler: (Response<SavedAdsWrapper, NSError>) ->
```

to

```
func responseSavedAdsArray(_ completionHandler: (DataResponse<SavedAdsWrapper>) ->
```

**EDITED**

```
let responseSerializer = ResponseSerializer<SavedAdsWrapper, NSError> { request, response, data, error in
```

to

```
let responseSerializer = DataResponseSerializer<SavedAdsWrapper> { request, response, data, error in
```

Comment: That fixed the first error but I still get: use of unresolved identifier ResponseSerializer

Comment: isn't it same too? try DataResponseSerializer<SavedAdsWrapper> :)

Comment: My bad! was a typo :)